# Using ANY/ALL in SQL to show highest entry in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I'm practicing for an exam and stuck on this question:

> Write a SQL statement to find which customer name has the
>   highest balance out of all the Balances. (You must use either ALL or ANY).

An example (also the highest balance) row from the table `Deposit`

```
INSERT INTO Deposit(customerName, branchName, accountNumber, balance)      
VALUES ('Jones', 'HFE', '42', '4100.00');
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT customerName
FROM Deposit
WHERE balance > ALL
(SELECT balance
FROM Deposit
WHERE balance >= balance);
```

How can I fix this to make the customer name with the highest balance display?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have data like this:

```
create table deposit ( customerName, balance) as (
    select 'cust1', 100 from dual UNION ALL
    select 'cust2', 500 from dual UNION ALL
    select 'cust3', 500 from dual UNION ALL
    select 'cust4', 400 from dual UNION ALL
    select 'cust5', 400 from dual
)
```

You need:

```
select customerName
from deposit
where balance >= ALL ( select balance from deposit)
```

that gives:

```
cust2
cust3
```

What goes wrong in your code:

- you have an unuseful `where` condition: not only this condition simply checks a column against itself, but it is unuseful, because you simply want your resulting `customerName` to have a balance greater than everyone's, with no conditions
- you have a strict `>` instead of `>=`, thus not matching any value

Comment: awesome,  thanks I see my mistakes and how to correct them!